# how to install windows 7 from hird disk from H:\Setup7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, installation

i have 2 hard disk and now i using windows 7 and old windows xp in another haskdisk in patition C: and datain D:, E: i would like to install new windows 7 
and not have dvd drive but hard disk have data in H: and i have H:\Setup7 for setup windows
and some data i have in H: how to setup its?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Win7 on HDD . Firstly download Daemon Tools . Download Win7 image and  mount it to Daemon virtual drive. Now you access your Virtual CD/DVD and install it normally on every partition you want .

The missing one when you do this method is you won't format your hard disk :)

Comment: now i am using windows xp?

Comment: Sure . I installed for my friend yesterday :)